# Best practice : when to load data from remote DB

Tags: java, android, database, performance

When I make an app, I always wonder when is the best moment to load data from a remote database. 
If the app ask for a login screen, then:

1. Is it better to launch every data from remote DB at his time, and then use them in the app? This way, the app is much faster after the login screen (no more queries needed to retrive some data)
2. Is it better to load data only when we need to use them (for example, display some data from DB into the app). This way, the login is much faster, but the app can be slower than the first case.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the scenario, but I would go with option 2: First, the user is granted the access and you retrieve the data from your backend when needed.

Imagine a very simple scenario where the user logs in to see a list of products he can work with (add and remove). The solution would consist of 2 screens:

- A login screen to manage user access
- product list screen to work with products

For me, in a good design each screen has its own resposibility, and each screen should query only the data that it is going to manage.

- The login screen responsibility would be only to perform the login and then navigate to the product screen.
- The product screen responsibility would be retrieve the products, show them and store them when the user has ended the editings.

If your login screen queries the product data to pass it to the product screen, you are coupling the login screen and the product data.

Anyway, if you have a set of static data that can be used by several screens (for example product categories), you can query them the first time you need them and store them in a cache for further accesses.

Another scenario could be if there can be conectivity problems. In this case the best solution could be to download a set of data that the user can work with, edit them and them upload them to the backend (taking into account the possible concurrency issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to logIn your user you have to call the remote DB to authenticate the user. I do not see where you are able to do this without the remote db. 
Otherwise you are correct that you should only query the DB if you want to show the data you get.

Comment: I mean for example, if the user for example have  some cars or some houses etc ... Which are also in DB.

Comment: Hmmm, I do not really get your point. Sorry. What do you mean be some cars / some houses?